# Reverse first n elements of a list in LISP

Tags: list, lisp, reverse

Assume I have the list (3 1 4 5 2) with the name "numbers". I am looking for a command that will reverse the list from index 0 up to an arbitrary index, i.e. (reverse numbers 2) which will give the new list as (4 1 3 5 2).

I've tried googling, but could not find a suitable function and I'm too much of a newbie to write the function myself at this stage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which dialect of Lisp are you using? Here's a Scheme solution (using [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)):

```
(require srfi/1)    ; assuming you're using Racket
(define (reverse-first-n lst n)
  (call-with-values (lambda ()
                      (split-at lst n))
                    append-reverse!))
```

I made the function really "reverse the first n elements" like your title says, and unlike your question description. So for example:

```
> (reverse-first-n '(3 1 4 5 2) 2)
'(1 3 4 5 2)
> (reverse-first-n '(3 1 4 5 2) 3)
'(4 1 3 5 2)
```

---

As requested by the OP, here's a Common Lisp version. sds already posted a pretty decent version, so the version I'm writing is a more direct port of my Scheme solution (`append-reverse!` ⇒ `nreconc`; `call-with-values` ⇒ `multiple-value-call`; and I'm porting SRFI 1's `split-at` to CL):

```
(defun split-at (list n)
  (if (zerop n)
      (values '() list)
      (multiple-value-bind (prefix suffix)
                           (split-at (cdr list) (1- n))
        (values (cons (car list) prefix) suffix))))

(defun reverse-first-n (list n)
  (multiple-value-call #'nreconc (split-at list n)))
```

(Why `split-at`? Its purpose is to provide both the `take` (`subseq`) and `drop` (`nthcdr`) with only one traversal of the input list.)

Comment: Sorry, it's CLisp. Will the above code work if I change define to defun, etc?

Comment: No, SRFIs are Scheme-only. I'll see if I can cook up a CL version.

Comment: Okay, I added a CL version. But since I'm not seasoned in CL, it may not be the best solution there is....

Comment: The CL version wastes a lot of memory.

Comment: @sds That's fine, your version seems plenty good, so I edited my post to instead be a CL port of the Scheme version (which is, in my view, the optimal way to implement it in Scheme).

Comment: Oh, and my revised answer prompted me to try to implement `multiple-value-call` in Scheme, and here's my implementation: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29385/multiple-value-call-in-scheme (though, for my current answer, `call-with-values` is perfectly adequate, of course).

Answer (score 6):

Simple CL version based on the libary functions:

```
(defun reverse-first-n (list n)
  (nreconc (subseq list 0 n) (nthcdr n list)))
```

1. This is memory-optimal, i.e., it does not allocate unnecessarily:

   - no need to copy the tail, thus [nthcdr](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nthcdr.htm) instead of [subseq](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_subseq.htm)
   - [`revappend`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_revapp.htm) copies the 1st argument which is a fresh list anyway, so `nreconc` is more economical.
2. This version is speed-suboptimal, because it traverses `list` to the `n`th position **3** times - once in `subseq`, once in `nthcdr`, and then once in `nreconc`.

Here is the optimal verion:

```
(defun reverse-first-n (list n)
  (if (or (= n 0) (= n 1))
      list
      (do* ((tail (list (pop list)))
            (head tail (cons (pop list) head))
            (count (1- n) (1- count)))
           ((zerop count)
            (setf (cdr tail) list)
            head))))
```

Note that there is very little chance that this is the performance bottleneck in your code. My main purpose in providing the second version is to show how much time and effort the extensive and well-designed CL library saves you.

Comment: `nreconc` written wrong in code. Amazing how many batteries are included in CL :)